# Error handling that prompt the user to enter only integer greater than 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, error-handling, integer

I am trying to write a Python function that asks for an input of integer greater than 1 and return or print the input value.

For example when the code is being run:
**Error case 1:**
Enter an integer greater than 1: 1
Output: Please enter a number greater than 1:

**Error case 2:**
Enter an integer greater than 1: abc345
Output: Please enter integer values only:

If it is just to handle error case 1, it is easy, we can just use the while loop. But to also include the case for non-integer input, my code always crashes.

Here is my function:

```
    def mult_digits():
        x = input("Enter an integer greater than 1: ")    
        while type(x) is not int:
            try:
                while int(x) <= 1:
                    x = input("Please enter a number greater than 1: ")
                    x = int(x)
            except ValueError:
                  x = input("Please enter integer values only: ")
                  x = int(x)       
        print(f"Yes, you have entered {x}.")
```

The problem with my code is that int("a") will result in invalid literal for int() with base 10 error. Since the input() function always return a string and we need to check whether or not the string can be converted to integer, we need the int() function, but this is exactly where the problem is.

I have tried many different variations of the code, including using for loop to scan the input value for any non-integer character, but it is not that efficient and still crashes. I have also tried a while loop that ended up creating an infinite loop.

Could somebody please give some help? Is there any better way to write this function? I really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you make things too complicated. Basically if someone enters a value you first pass it through the `int(..)` function, and if that does not error, you check if it is larger than one, so we can write a `while` loop that keeps iterating until the value is valid, like:

```
def mult_digits():
    msg = "Enter an integer greater than 1: "
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        x = input(msg)  
        try:
            x = int(x)
        except ValueError:
            msg = "Please enter integer values only: "
        else:
            valid = x > 1
            if not valid:
                msg = "Enter an integer greater than 1: "
    print(f"Yes, you have entered {x}.")
```

So we simply perform the checking *in* the `while` loop (ideally you encapsulate that in a method as well), and in case the `int(..)` raises a `Value` error, the content is still not valid, and we can even change the `msg`. In case the conversion itself does not raises any errors, we can check the constraint, and again give a helpful message.

We keep doing that until `valid` is set to `True`, and then we print the value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, and thanks for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

```
def mult_digits():
    x = input("Enter an integer greater than 1: ")
    while True:
        try:
            while int(x) <= 1:
                x = input("Please enter a number greater than 1: ")
                x = int(x)
            if x > 1:
                    break
        except ValueError:
            x = input("Please enter integer values only: ")

    print(f"Yes, you have entered {x}.")
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

So I saw this while at work when it was posted to code review. I wanted to answer I but had to wait until I got home. I broke your block out into two blocks, one that gets input (I hate redundant code) and one that executes the check and calls for input. I also added a clear error message for digits and non-digits. I am posting the complete code here:

```
# -*-coding: utf-8-*-
# !/usr/bin/python3.6

import sys


def multi_digits():
    digit = get_input()
    x = True

    while x:
        if digit in '23456789':
            print(f'Yes,you have entered {digit}.')
            x = False
        # In elif it looks like int(digit) may throw an error if it isn't a digit but
        # because of the way if statements work this wont happen. The if statement excutes
        # digit.isdigit() first, if it returns false it doesn't care about the second condition so
        # int(digit) only is checked after we confirm digit is actually a digit.
        elif digit.isdigit() and int(digit) <= 1:
            print('Invalid input: Digit was not greater than 1')
            digit = get_input()
        else:
            print('Invalid input: no letters allowed')
            digit = get_input()


def get_input() -> str:
    return input('Enter an integer greater than 1: ')


def main():
    multi_digits()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, an interesting approach.